# Trying to separate bar in histogram, and set custom labels

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have multiple CSV files containing a single line like this :

`y,ymin,ymax`

For example:

`35.4587,36.6542,34.3546`

I want to do a histogram with error bars that looks like this:

[image]

But instead I have this:

[image]

Because I don't understand how to separate the boxes, and how to give them arbitrary labels, regardless of the data I'm plotting.

Here is my code so far:

```
reset

set datafile separator ','

set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 2
set style data histograms

set ylabel 'time (seconds)'

plot 'data1.csv' using 1:2:3 notitle, \
'data2.csv' using 1:2:3 notitle, \
'data3.csv' using 1:2:3 notitle, \
'data4.csv' using 1:2:3 notitle
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I do not really get along with the histogram styles. But I'm sure there is a way to achieve what you want. One alternative way would be to just draw it "manually" using `with boxes` and `with yerrorbars` and tune it as you like. Something like this, which can certainly be optimized, e.g. with a loop, depending on your data.

**Code:**

```
### "manual" histogram with errorbars
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
60 58 62
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
37 36 38
EOD

$Data3 <<EOD
46 44 48
EOD

$Data4 <<EOD
63 61 65
EOD

set boxwidth 0.4
unset key
set xrange [0.5:4.5]
set yrange [35:70]

set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set errorbars lw 2 ls -1

plot $Data1 u (1):1:xtic("Some text")        w boxes lc 1, '' u (1):1:2:3 w yerrorbars pt -1, \
     $Data2 u (2):1:xtic("Some other text")  w boxes lc 2, '' u (2):1:2:3 w yerrorbars pt -1, \
     $Data3 u (3):1:xtic("Arbitrary text")   w boxes lc 3, '' u (3):1:2:3 w yerrorbars pt -1, \
     $Data4 u (4):1:xtic("Yet another text") w boxes lc 4, '' u (4):1:2:3 w yerrorbars pt -1
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate plotting style `with boxerrorbars`. It has several variants depending on what the data columns contain.  The 5 column form should work for you:
    `5 columns:  x  y  ylow  yhigh  xdelta`
You can add a 6th column for the tic labels.

```
$Data1 <<EOD
60 58 62
EOD
$Data2 <<EOD
37 36 38
EOD
$Data3 <<EOD
46 44 48
EOD
$Data4 <<EOD
63 61 65
EOD

array titles = ["One potato", "Two potato", "Three potato", "Four"]

unset key
set border 3
set tics nomirror
set style fill solid border lc "black"
set style data boxerrorbars
set xrange [0:5]

plot for [i=1:4] sprintf("$Data%d",i) using (i):1:2:3:(.2):xticlabel(titles[i])
```

[image]